# Date Setting to 01/01/0001 00:00:00 in MVC 3.0 Web Application after submit button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, postback

I have a designed a form for my MVC Web application with which the user can enter details . One of the details is Date which he /she can choose from a DateTime Picker.

After entering all the details including Date , I submit the form but instead of going to the next page, **the same form reloads with a Validation Error on Date Field and setting 01/01/0001 00:00:00 as the Date.**

What is the solution  ?

I have declared my datetime variable like this -

```
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime ShipmentDate { get; set; }
```

Is something missing in this ?

Technical Details :

I have deployed my MVC Application on **Windows Server 2012 . Database is SQL Server 2012 and Web Server is IIS 8 .**

When i run from my development version it is working fine ie - From Visual Studio 2012- Db SQL Server 2012 - IIS 7.5. But the above line is the live version which i want to work with.

Please help with the confusion.

One Possible solution can be the Out-of-context DateTimePicker File .When i tested the application, by entering the date eg: April 17, 2013.. it worked .

I have used a external .js file for the datetimePicker. This file's OS requirements were Windows 7 , Windows Vista.

I have deployed my application on Windows Server 2012 (even the datepickerFile on the server ) . Hence , I think , the file's JQuery Logic is not getting implemented and hence the date even after setting in the textBox of the form remains null.

Eventually, when we do a postback, the null value is returned to my model and the condition of Model.IsValid is checked for null ,which fails , and the view is recreated. Since, the default value of Datetime is  01/01/0001 00:00:00 , this value gets intialized in the dateTime field .

Regards,

Mangesh

Comment: Is it something to do with the culture settings of IIS 8 ?  some change in the Configuration file of IIS 8 ? because inmy development version it is working fine (IIS 7.5)

Comment: That usually corresponds to a null DateTime value. There's probably an error when you're posting the value ShipmentDate.

Comment: please go through the edited post once now .. :)

Comment: Check the value being posted back to the server. If there is a value sent back, there might be an error when parsing it, that would lead to the default value for date.

Comment: Model binding will also fail if the value cannot be parsed, this may be the cause of the null value you are seeing.

Comment: I solved the problem . You have to add a globilization tag in your Web.Config. This imports the settings to the server where you are deploying .

Comment: hence i just added this .  <globalization culture="en-US" />

Comment: I get the same problem when using DisplayFormatString to change floating-point format (e.g. "1,234.56"). When posted back, the value is 0.0 instead of 1234.56. This appears to be a MVC bug.

Answer (score 2):

That happens when culture info is incorrect, you need to configure the web.conf

```
<system.web>    
    <globalization culture="en-US" />
</system.web>
```

[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28VS.80%29.aspx) is a list of the different cultures info depend from the country you are.

This is a problem of IIS 8.0 and newer.